# Hive Join query adds \n in each row

Tags: sql, hive

In Hive I am joining 2 tables using Left Outer Join. After join, I can see '\n' at the end of each row. 
My query looks like

```
SELECT o1.merchantid, o1.countriesvrnstatus, o1.sellerofferlevelvcsconfigstatus, o2.programs
FROM ${input1} o1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ${input2} o2 
ON (o1.merchantid = o2.merchantid);
```

Output looks like this

> > AJEJ61SA2GGJN {"AT":{"s":"VERIFIED"}} FULL    \n
> >
> > A3D91EAFW36ZGY    {"IT":{"s":"VERIFIED"}} FULL    \n
> >
> > A338I5YPDUCU3R    {"DE":{"s":"VERIFIED"}} FULL    \n

How to remove \n from each row?

Answer (score 0):

If the last column value has `'\n'` then use `regex_replace(column_name,'\\n','')` on the last column

```
SELECT 
       o1.merchantid, 
       o1.countriesvrnstatus, 
       o1.sellerofferlevelvcsconfigstatus, 
       regex_replace(o2.programs,'\\n','')
FROM ${input1} o1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ${input2} o2 
ON (o1.merchantid = o2.merchantid);
```

Comment: Tried running this query but it didn't help. No any column contains value '\n'. I just tried DataFormat which I was using for output in Hive from tsv to csv and issue got resolved.